# Error while importing csv file in magento 2

Tags: magento2, import, csv, table-rates

When I enter AE-SH in the state/region column of csv file it shows the error
"We couldn't import this file because of these errors: Please correct Region/State "SH" in the Row #19."

Comment: Try opening the csv in Notepad++ and go Encoding> Convert to UTF-8-BOM then save. And try again

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But it didn't worked.What to do:(

Comment: Can you please share the csv

Comment: Country,Region/State,Zip/Postal Code,Weight (and above),Shipping Price   ARE,SH,*,0.1,19
ARE,SH,*,5.1,21
ARE,SH,*,6.1,23
ARE,SH,*,7.1,25
ARE,DU,*,0.1,19
ARE,DU,*,5.1,21
ARE,DU,*,6.1,23
ARE,DU,*,7.1,25

Comment: AE-SH is which state for you are used ?

Comment: for sharja in UAE

Comment: UAE states/region not supported so you have to add states/region by script to database.

Comment: ok. i will do it.

Comment: i have 1more doubt. that i need to set different shipping cost based on some source and destination places. can you help me to write the csv file?

Comment: You can set shipping cost based on destination plages.

Comment: where i should make changes?

Answer (score 0):

In your comment above **ARE,SH,,0.1,19**. The error is you separate it with 2 comma *,,*. Try this: **ARE,SH,0.1,19** or open the CSV file with notepad++.
Example Screenshot:

[image]